# How may I load Images in Pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I wrote this command to load images in **Pygame Python**

```
sun_img = pygame.image.load('img/sun.png')
bg_img = pygame.image.load('img/sky.png')


run= True
while run:

    screen.blit(bg_img, (0, 0))
    screen.blit(sun_img, (100, 100))
```

But the image wasn't loaded when I ran the program. Also, I didn't get any type of error.
**Please check if I am doing anything wrong or tell me what to do!!**

Comment: Can you share your full code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to update the display and to handle the events:

```py
run= True
while run:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    screen.blit(bg_img, (0, 0))
    screen.blit(sun_img, (100, 100))

    pygame.dispaly.flip()
```

The typical PyGame application loop has to:

- handle the events by either [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump) or [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get).
- update the game states and positions of objects dependent on the input events and time (respectively frames)
- clear the entire display or draw the background
- draw the entire scene (`blit` all the objects)
- update the display by either [`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) or [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip)

You are actually drawing on a [`Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) object. If you draw on the *Surface* associated to the PyGame display, this is not immediately visible in the display. The changes become visibel, when the display is updated with either [`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) or [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip).

See [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip):

> This will update the contents of the entire display.

See [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get) respectively [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump):

> For each frame of your game, you will need to make some sort of call to the event queue. This ensures your program can internally interact with the rest of the operating system.

Answer (score 0):

Add `pygame.display.update()` at the end and it should work.

Also, to prevent window lag, use this event handling code in your loop:

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                run = False
```